# Writing a sequence of numbers like: 1 22 333 4444 55555 via recursion c++

Tags: c++

I have to write a code in c++ without loops, which would display a monotonic sequence of numbers like 1 22 333 to the number I input, so number k is repeating k times. It's like i input 6, the code would display 1 22 333 4444 55555 666666. It has to be via recursion.

For now, if i cin >> 15 output is a row of numbers from 1 to 15. I have a feeling this is extremely easy but nothing crosses my mind right now.
This is my attemp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x;

void func(int n) 
{
    if(n>=1){
        func(n-1);
        std::cout<< n << " ";
    }   
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a natural number: ";
    cin >> x;
    func(x);
}
```

Comment: You need to use a loop to print the value of `n` `n` times followed by one space.

Comment: and call that function in another loop

Comment: Well, you might want to replace the outer loop with recursion

Comment: You have two repeating patterns (print x n times, and print from 1 to n), so you're going to need two recursive functions to do the whole thing.  The second one will call the first one in addition to calling itself.

Comment: *"For now, if i cin >> 15 output is a row of numbers from 1 to 15."* -- This is progress. I recommend putting aside your full assignment for now and try to solve a simpler one: *display a repeating sequence of numbers like 333 of the number I input, so number k is repeating k times.* This is your "inner" project; your current code addresses the "outer" project. Combining two solutions should be easy compared to each solution by itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There you go:

```
#include <iostream>

int x{0};

void another_func(int n, int counter) 
{
    if (counter-- > 0) {
        std::cout << n;
        another_func(n, counter);
    }
}

void func(int n) 
{
    if(n>=1){
        func(n-1);
        another_func(n, n);
        //for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        //    std::cout << n;
        std::cout << " ";
    }   
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a natural number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    func(x);
}
```